# How to show colours and clear when running React development server in eshell?

Tags: shell, eshell, colors, term

Here is how the usual Ubuntu terminal looks when you run the React development serving using `npm start` and make changes to your source:

[image: ubuntu terminal]

Say the server was already running and you tried to do `npm start` again, you get notified in a colourful message:

[image]

And, if you say no, it exits cleanly.

However, I use eshell. This is how the same thing (the react dev. server) looks in eshell:
[image]

Observe how the output is appended onto the previous contents instead of clearing the screen. The colours are also missing. If the server is already running, this is how the eshell prompt looks like:

[image]

This is kind of a mess. Once you say no, it does not exit cleanly but shows the same message again before exiting.

My question is, is there a way to make eshell more like the ubuntu terminal? Is there a modern terminal package for Emacs that could handle these kind of things?

Comment: Eshell is, as its name suggests a shell. Sure, you can add some hacks to handle color escape codes, but you cannot make it handle everything xterm does without turning it into a terminal emulator. It's not a "modern terminal package".

Comment: I have forever been confused about the differences between consoles, terminals, cmds, shells, bashes and so forth, To me, they all looked like a command line interface to an operating system. I tried reading at places like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/144666/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-console-and-terminal) but that only confuses me more. It looks like when you run `M x term`, it asks to run `/bin/bash`, Bash according to the link I put before is "the most common shell in modern linux systems", so `M x term` also runs a shell which is bash, wait what?

Comment: Yes, the terminal emulator runs a program, typically a shell like bash. It doesn't have to though, it might as well run ssh, a serial console, ...

Comment: The relationship between a terminal and a shell is much the same as the relationship between a web browser and a web page. A terminal can display many things, but mostly we use it to display the output of a shell like Bash. A web browser can display many things too, but we often use it to display a web page like Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, color handling works out of the box for me with eshell

[image: colortest output]

Anything more complicated than that is the task of a terminal emulator, not a shell. Eshell is a replacement for shells, like bash, zsh, you name it, its original purpose was a more familiar environment for developers using Emacs on Windows.

If you want a terminal emulator which runs a shell (like bash or zsh) and handles these escape sequences, your choices are term.el with the `M-x term` and `M-x ansi-term` commands and more recently, the [vterm](https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm) package.  It might work better for you as it has greater compatibility with xterm (for some reason lots of software in the node.js ecosystem assumes you're using xterm) due to its strategy of letting libvterm handle all the hard work.  This means however that you'll need Emacs with dynamic modules support and have to compile the module yourself.

Comment: When I run `colortest` in `/usr/share/emacs/25.2/lisp/eshell`, I get: `colortest: command not found`. Is it because I am on an older version? How can I check the version eshell is on?

Comment: That's a program that's unrelated to Emacs, you'll have to install it separately. Any of the color testing programs will do.